# how to get facebook user album's id using php facebbok API

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to get facebook user albums id and I am using this code

```
$friendsalbum = $facebook->api("/userID/albums/");
```

where userID is the user facebook id
but it returm me empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Well i used this code in app

```
$albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums?fields=name,link');
```

[Here](http://apps.facebook.com/invite-sumair/?ref=bookmarks&count=0) is the sample app.

Comment: that is for getting your data after login.
is there any way to get any user albums from facebook using API?

Comment: use facebook offline_access to access a user's album even if he is not connected in real

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have the `friends_photos` permission set in your application and the following call should work

```
$friendsalbum = $facebook->api("/userID/albums/");
```

If it returns empty after this it means that the user's privacy setting is blocking you from accessing this data.

[image: How people bring your info to apps they use]